# How do i calculate total number of lambda invocations in AWS for the last month using cloudwatch metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

[image: Cloudwatch Metric Lambda Invocation]

I want to calculate the total number of invocation for all the lambdas in my AWS account for the last month. As shown in the picture there is the time period at top right where I specify the from and to time. As I understand that is the time period within which I calculate the number of invocations. There is also a Period column in the table below I don't understand its significance and changing it has a effect on the Invocation Count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Graph Options` tab you see on that screenshots and there you'll have 2 options for which value to display:

1. **Latest value**

   - This shows the value from the most recent period of your chosen time range.
     For example, if you choose 'Statistic - Minimum' and 'Period - 5 Minutes', it shows the minimum value from the latest 5-minute period of your chosen time range.
2. **Time range value**

   - This shows the value from the entire time range.
     For example, if you choose 'Statistic – Minimum', it shows the minimum value from your entire time range. The 'Period' setting has no effect on the value displayed.

If by *the last month* you mean last 30 days, then you would select option 1 above and change period of the metric to 30 days.

If you need the last calendar month (September 1st till September 30th), then you would select option 2 above and set the time range you need in the dashboard setting.

Comment: Thanks ! I wanted to see the total number of invocations hence what i did was selected the Statics to be SUM and after providing the time range of 30 days i also selected the period to be 30 days

Answer (score 1):

Graph the metric and timerange you want and add a Dynamic Label - "sum". The legend of the graph will then contain the sum of all datapoints for each metric you have graphed.